# URL.openConnection() doesn't wait for page to load fully

Tags: java, html, http, https, web-scraping

I am trying to load page from my University so that I can pull grades straight into my program. I am trying to use a `HttpsURLConnection`, but whenever I call `URL.openConnection` and send a `GET` request, I am returned a loading page with no useful information.

How can I fully load a page so that I am able to get data from the actual page instead of the loading page?

EDIT:
I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>The University of Auckland - PeopleSoft Logon....</title>
    <!--<base href="https://iam.auckland.ac.nz" />-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeInputType(oldElm, // a reference to the input element  iType, // value of the type property: 'text' or 'password'  iValue, // the default value, set to 'password' in the demo  blankValue, // true if the value should be empty, false otherwise  noFocus) {  // set to true if the element should not be given focus  if(!oldElm || !oldElm.parentNode || (iType.length<4) ||     !document.getElementById || !document.createElement) return;  var isMSIE=/*@cc_on!@*/false; //http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2007/03/sniff/  if(!isMSIE){    var newElm=document.createElement('input');    newElm.type=iType;  } else {    var newElm=document.createElement('span');    newElm.innerHTML='<input type="'+iType+'" name="'+oldElm.name+'">';    newElm=newElm.firstChild;  }  var props=['name','id','className','size','tabIndex','accessKey'];  for(var i=0,l=props.length;i<l;i++){    if(oldElm[props[i]]) newElm[props[i]]=oldElm[props[i]];  }  newElm.onfocus=function(){return function(){    if(this.hasFocus) return;    var newElm=changeInputType(this,'password',iValue,      (this.value.toLowerCase()==iValue.toLowerCase())?true:false);    if(newElm) newElm.hasFocus=true;  }}();  newElm.onblur=function(){return function(){    if(this.hasFocus)    if(this.value=='' || (this.value.toLowerCase()==iValue.toLowerCase())) {      changeInputType(this,'text',iValue,false,true);    }  }}(); // hasFocus is to prevent a loop where onfocus is triggered over and over again  newElm.hasFocus=false;  // some browsers need the value set before the element is added to the page  // while others need it set after  if(!blankValue) newElm.value=iValue;  oldElm.parentNode.replaceChild(newElm,oldElm);  if(!isMSIE && !blankValue) newElm.value=iValue;  if(!noFocus || typeof(noFocus)=='undefined') {    window.tempElm=newElm;    setTimeout("tempElm.hasFocus=true;tempElm.focus();",1);  }  return newElm;}function readCookie(name) {var nameEQ = name + "=";var ca = document.cookie.split(';');for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {  var c = ca[i];  while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);   if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {       if (c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length)!="(null)") {            return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);     }   }}return null;}function createCookie(name,value,days) {if (days) {  var date = new Date();  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));  var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();}else var expires = "";document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";}function createCookieSeconds(name,value,seconds) {if (seconds) {  var date = new Date();  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(seconds*1000));    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();} else var expires = "";document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";}function eraseCookie(name) {createCookie(name,"",-1);}// infinite loop detection var loopdetect=readCookie("loopdetect");if (loopdetect) {   loopdetect=parseInt(loopdetect)+1;} else {  loopdetect=0;}createCookieSeconds("loopdetect",loopdetect,15);
    </script>
    <link rel="icon" href="/plugins/uoa-style-0.2/images/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/plugins/bundle/bundle.css" />
    <!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bundle/0/bundle.js" ></script> -->
    <meta name="layout" content="transition" />
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function signin(form) {
                var docLoc = new String(document.location);
                var iLast = docLoc.lastIndexOf("?&");
                if (docLoc.length == (iLast + 2)) {
                    docLoc = docLoc.substring(0, iLast);
                }
                if (docLoc.indexOf("?cmd=") == -1 && docLoc.indexOf("?") != -1) {
                    if (docLoc.indexOf("&cmd=login") == -1) {
                        var i = docLoc.length - 1;
                        var j = docLoc.lastIndexOf("&");
                        if (j != -1 && i == j) {
                            form.action = docLoc + form.action.substring(form.action.indexOf("?") + 1, form.action.length);
                        } else {
                            form.action = docLoc + "&" + form.action.substring(form.action.indexOf("?") + 1, form.action.length);
                        }
                    } else {
                        form.action = docLoc; // form.action=docLoc.substring(0,docLoc.indexOf("&cmd=login"))+"&cmd=login"+docLoc.substring(docLoc.indexOf("&languageCd="),docLoc.length);         // 2011/09/25 - not sure why the above customisation was commented out, so left it commented out }} else {  form.action=docLoc;} var now=new Date(); form.timezoneOffset.value=now.getTimezoneOffset(); return ;}function setFocus(){try {document.login.userid.focus()}catch (e)    {};return;}function submitAction(form){signin(form);form.action=form.action.replace("errorCode=106","");form.Submit.disabled=true;form.submit();}
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="uoaOnLoad()" style="cursor:progress">
    <div id="uoa_loading" style="visibility:visible;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;" align="right">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="main-body-left">
                <div id="main-body-right">
                    <div id="main-body">
                        <div id="mastHeader_round">
                            <div class="head">
                                <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz" class="logo" title="The University of Auckland" tabindex="-1"><img src="/plugins/uoa-style-0.2/images/logo.png" alt="The University of Auckland" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="container" class="main-container">
                            <div class="page-loading">Loading....</div>
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mastFooter">
                            <p id="copyright"><a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/" target="_self">Copyright &copy; The University of Auckland</a>
                            </p>
                            <p id="footerLogo">
                                <a target="_blank" title="APRU" href="http://apru.nus.edu.sg/" id="apru"> </a>
                                <a target="_blank" title="Universitas" href="http://www.universitas21.com/" id="universitas"> </a>
                            </p>
                            <p id="footerNav"><a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/about/the-university/atoz-directory">A to Z Directory</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/site-map">Site map</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/accessibility">Accessibility</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/copyright">Copyright</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/disclaimer">Disclaimer</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/privacy">Privacy</a> | <a href="mailto:contactus@auckland.ac.nz">Feedback on this page</a>
                            </p>
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="uoa_ssobody" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="main-body-left">
                <div id="main-body-right">
                    <div id="main-body">
                        <div id="mastHeader_round">
                            <div class="head">
                                <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz" class="logo" title="The University of Auckland" tabindex="-1"><img src="/plugins/uoa-style-0.2/images/logo.png" alt="The University of Auckland" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="container" class="main-container">
                            <div id="login" class="form-dialog">
                                <h1>The University of Auckland</h1>
                                <fieldset class="login">
                                    <legend>System Information</legend>
                                    <!--        <div class="formElement">                   <div class="field textContainer">                   </div>              </div>              <div class="formElement">                   <div class="field textContainer">                   </div>              </div>-->
                                    <div class="login-options">
                                        <div style="width:94%;text-align:left;position:relative;left:3%;">
                                            <p> <font size=2><font color=red><b><br><div id="extra-errors">You may not have access to the system you have attempted to sign in to.</div></b><br></font> </div>
                                        <hr>
                                        <br>
                                        <div style="width:94%;text-align:left;position:relative;left:3%;"> If you are an applicant and want to review the status of your applications or submit a new application, sign in to:
                                            <br> <a href="https://apply.auckland.ac.nz">https://apply.auckland.ac.nz</a>
                                            <br>
                                            <br> Enrolled students should sign in to:
                                            <br> <a href="https://www.student.auckland.ac.nz">https://www.student.auckland.ac.nz</a>
                                            <br>
                                            <br> To update your personal details, visit:
                                            <br> <a href="https://iam.auckland.ac.nz/identity">https://iam.auckland.ac.nz/identity</a>
                                            <br>
                                            <br> If you believe you have received this message in error, please call
                                            <br>0800 61 62 63 (New Zealand only) or +64 9 373 7999.
                                            <br>
                                            <br> </font>
                                        </div>
                                        </font>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div id="message" class="form-dialog">
                                <h3>Protect your privacy</h3>
                                <p>Remember to always log out by <a href="https://wiki.auckland.ac.nz/display/IAMHELP/How+to+Single-Log-Out+by+completely+exiting+your+browser">completely exiting your browser</a> when you leave the computer.</p>
                                <p>This will protect your personal information from being accessed by subsequent users.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mastFooter">
                            <p id="copyright"><a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/" target="_self">Copyright &copy; The University of Auckland</a>
                            </p>
                            <p id="footerLogo">
                                <a target="_blank" title="APRU" href="http://apru.nus.edu.sg/" id="apru"> </a>
                                <a target="_blank" title="Universitas" href="http://www.universitas21.com/" id="universitas"> </a>
                            </p>
                            <p id="footerNav"><a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/about/the-university/atoz-directory">A to Z Directory</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/site-map">Site map</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/accessibility">Accessibility</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/copyright">Copyright</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/disclaimer">Disclaimer</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/privacy">Privacy</a> | <a href="mailto:contactus@auckland.ac.nz">Feedback on this page</a>
                            </p>
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="uoa_vanillabody" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="main-body-left">
                <div id="main-body-right">
                    <div id="main-body">
                        <div id="mastHeader_round">
                            <div class="head">
                                <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz" class="logo" title="The University of Auckland" tabindex="-1"><img src="/plugins/uoa-style-0.2/images/logo.png" alt="The University of Auckland" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="container" class="main-container">
                            <div id="login" class="form-dialog">
                                <h1>The University of Auckland</h1>
                                <fieldset class="login">
                                    <legend>PeopleSoft login</legend>
                                    <!--        <div class="formElement">                   <div class="field textContainer">                   </div>              </div>              <div class="formElement">                   <div class="field textContainer">                   </div>              </div>-->
                                    <div class="login-options">
                                        <form action="?cmd=login&languageCd=ENG" method="post" id="login" name="login" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="signin(document.login)">
                                            <p>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="timezoneOffset" value="0">User ID:
                                                <input id="userid" name="userid" type="text" class="pslogineditbox" value="" size="15">
                                                <br>Password:
                                                <input type="hidden" id="pwd" name="pwd" class="pslogineditbox" size="15">
                                                <br>
                                                <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="psloginbutton" value="Sign In" onclick="submitAction(document.login)">
                                                <br>
                                                <br>
                                                <script>
                                                    document.write("<br>To set trace flags, click <a href='" + document.location + "&trace=y'>here</a>");
                                                </script><font color=red><br><b><br></b></font>
                                            </p>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div id="message" class="form-dialog">
                                <h3>Protect your privacy</h3>
                                <p>Remember to always log out by <a href="https://wiki.auckland.ac.nz/display/IAMHELP/How+to+Single-Log-Out+by+completely+exiting+your+browser">completely exiting your browser</a> when you leave the computer.</p>
                                <p>This will protect your personal information from being accessed by subsequent users.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mastFooter">
                            <p id="copyright"><a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/" target="_self">Copyright &copy; The University of Auckland</a>
                            </p>
                            <p id="footerLogo">
                                <a target="_blank" title="APRU" href="http://apru.nus.edu.sg/" id="apru"> </a>
                                <a target="_blank" title="Universitas" href="http://www.universitas21.com/" id="universitas"> </a>
                            </p>
                            <p id="footerNav"><a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/about/the-university/atoz-directory">A to Z Directory</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/site-map">Site map</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/accessibility">Accessibility</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/copyright">Copyright</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/disclaimer">Disclaimer</a> | <a href="http://www.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/home/privacy">Privacy</a> | <a href="mailto:contactus@auckland.ac.nz">Feedback on this page</a>
                            </p>
                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function uoaOnLoad() {
                var uoa_docLoc = new String(document.location);
                var uoa_logout = ((uoa_docLoc.indexOf("&cmd=logout") != -1) || (uoa_docLoc.indexOf("?cmd=logout") != -1));
                var uoa_login = ((uoa_docLoc.indexOf("&cmd=login") != -1) || (uoa_docLoc.indexOf("?cmd=login") != -1));
                var uoa_nosso = ((uoa_docLoc.indexOf("&sso=n") != -1) || (uoa_docLoc.indexOf("?sso=n") != -1));
                var uoa_query = (uoa_docLoc.indexOf("?") != -1);
                var uoa_slashlast = (uoa_docLoc.charAt(uoa_docLoc.length - 1) == "/");
                if (loopdetect > 5) {
                    uoa_logout = true;
                    uoa_login = false;
                    document.getElementById('extra-errors').innerHTML = "Cookie problem detected, login terminated. <BR><br></font><font color=black>Please close all your browser windows and then try again.";
                } else if (uoa_docLoc.indexOf("cmd=expire") != -1) {
                    document.getElementById('extra-errors').innerHTML = "Your connection has expired.<br><br></font><font color=black>You can try logging in again by <a href='" + uoa_docLoc.replace("cmd=expire", "cmd=login") + "'>clicking here</a>, or if that doesn't work, you will need to close all your browser windows and then try again.";
                    uoa_logout = true;
                    uoa_login = false;
                }
                if (!((uoa_login) || (uoa_logout))) {
                    if (uoa_query) {
                        window.location = uoa_docLoc + "&cmd=login&languageCd=ENG";
                    } else {
                        if (uoa_slashlast) {
                            window.location = uoa_docLoc + "?cmd=login&languageCd=ENG";
                        } else {
                            window.location = uoa_docLoc + "/?cmd=login&languageCd=ENG";
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!uoa_nosso) {
                        if (uoa_login) {
                            if (("" == "User ID and Password are required.") || ("" == "")) {
                                var uoa_randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000001) var uoa_ssouser_cookie = readCookie("uoa_ssouser");
                                eraseCookie("uoa_ssouser");
                                eraseCookie("uoa_ssouser");
                                eraseCookie("uoa_ssouser");
                                if ((uoa_ssouser_cookie == "(null)") || (uoa_ssouser_cookie == null)) {
                                    uoa_ssouser_cookie = "";
                                }
                                if (("" == uoa_ssouser_cookie) || ("" == "")) {
                                    var uoa_ssouser = uoa_ssouser_cookie + "*sso";
                                } else {
                                    var uoa_ssouser = uoa_ssouser_cookie + "*";
                                }
                                document.login.userid.value = uoa_ssouser;
                                document.login.pwd.value = "ssologin" + uoa_randomnumber;
                                submitAction(document.login);
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById("uoa_loading").style.visibility = "hidden";
                                document.getElementById("uoa_ssobody").style.visibility = "visible";
                                document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
                            }
                        } else {
                            if ((uoa_logout) && (document.getElementById('extra-errors').innerHTML == "You may not have access to the system you have attempted to sign in to.")) {
                                document.getElementById('extra-errors').innerHTML = "</font><font color=black>You've been logged out. <br><BR>You can try logging in again by <a href='" + uoa_docLoc.replace("cmd=logout", "cmd=login") + "'>clicking here</a>.";
                            }
                            document.getElementById("uoa_loading").style.visibility = "hidden";
                            document.getElementById("uoa_ssobody").style.visibility = "visible";
                            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
                        }
                    } else {
                        document.login.action = document.login.action + "&sso=n";
                        document.getElementById("uoa_loading").style.visibility = "hidden";
                        document.getElementById("uoa_ssobody").style.visibility = "hidden";
                        document.getElementById("uoa_vanillabody").style.visibility = "visible"; //     document.login.pwd.type="password"; IE8 doesn't like this      changeInputType(document.getElementById('pwd'),'password','',true,true);     document.body.style.cursor='default';}}}
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT 2: My `GET` method:

```
private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // default is GET
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        // act like a browser
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        if (cookies != null) {
            for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
                conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
            }
        }       

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);


        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);

        }
        System.out.println(conn.getURL());
        in.close();

        // Get the response cookies
        setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

        return response.toString();

    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can paste the stuff you get by `URL.openConnection` here and specify what exactly do you want to get from it? In particular, I mean the code  and the response you get.

Comment: Is the side that you try to connect require login? If yes, did you handle the http header and session info correctly?

Comment: Yeah a login was required - I think I'm handling it correctly, but I'm not 100% sure. I've edited my post to include my 'GET' method.

Answer (score 0):

Which servlet is your URL referencing, PSC or PSP?

The correct link for screen scraping peoplesoft would be PSC as PSP acts as a reverse proxy, loading the content (psc) in an iFrame.  This can cause what youre seeing.

The HTTP Get request you are making, if hitting the psp servlet, will respond back 200 while the iFrame is loading with the psc content.  Really you just need the psc content, so reference that directly.